# Overstand theme set up issue

Tags: customization

I've just begun setting up the overstand theme to work with my blog, but I've run into a problem. Check out my site: http://beachief.com/, the problem is pretty obvious. Those two black categories have been like that since I first installed the theme - I have done nothing to change them. I'd like those two areas to stretch out across the entire page. They are both set to use the "latest2" class which is coded to be 465px, but neither are responding to it. What's wrong?

You can find the files for the overstand theme here:http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=2212542

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should replace this code:**

```
ul.latestoneandhalf {
    float:left;
    padding-right:15px;
    width:225px;
}
```

**With this:**

```
ul.latestoneandhalf {
    float:left;
    padding-right:15px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your style.css, on line ~ 878, modify the "width" line so that the block reads:

```
ul.latestoneandhalf {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 465px;
}
```